# When is an impulsive force dissipative?

Tags: energy, momentum, energy-conservation, collision, dissipation

Let's say you have a ball attached to a string and you let it fall vertically from the point of suspension of the string. There's an impulse when the string becomes taut and the ball comes to rest. Energy isn't conserved in this case.

Now, suppose a ball is hanging from the ceiling with the help of a string. You let a particle fall from the point of suspension of the string. The particle strikes the ball, undergoes an elastic collision and bounces back. Tension is again an impulsive force, but energy is conserved in this case.

Why is Tension dissipative in the first case but not the second?

Comment: @ Let's think in terms of forces. In the first case, the ball comes to rest because the net force is zero. However, just because velocity is zero does not mean force is zero because force is roughly related to change in velocity over change in time. In the second case, when the ball is hit, it pulls on the string and soon has zero velocity (this is fine because due to external forces momentum is not conserved). However, the net force on the ball is not zero (this is due to ball's and string's properties) and so the ball moves up again. Here dissipation is due to air resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Energy isn't conserved in this case.*
I think what you meant to say is that kinetic energy is not conserved in this case.

Imagine doing the same experiment but using a spring instead of the string.
The mass on the end would probably execute damped harmonic motion about its final equilibrium position.
It is the mechanical energy (sum of kinetic energy and potential energy) of the spring-mass system which is dissipated as heat due to air resistance.

With the string the problem is that when you extend it there is permanent deformation of the string as the fibres slip by one another with frictional forces converting the mechanical energy of the system into heat.

In your other example, with the implication that the string never becomes taut, the collision is elastic because the objects deform but then return to their original shape undamaged, ie no permanent deformation of the objects as they act like ideal springs during the collision.

Comment: Alright, I get what's happening, thank you.